# RVM 1.25.22 (stable) error on "rvm use"

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, rvm, macruby

Got error like this:

```
MacRuby can only be installed on a Darwin OS.
macruby-0.12 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install macruby-0.12'
```

when trying to

```
rvm use
```

after

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

on fresh ubuntu 12.04. On my home pc and at one VPS.
If I use

```
rvm use 2.1.1
```

directly, for example, its OK and I can use RVM. Still sometimes at scripting it makes some troubles. And writing rvm use... each time I open terminal window is annoying.
What is that? Cant google anything related to macruby and ubuntu.
Home PC is ubuntu 12.04. VPS was x86 as far as I remember.
I tried to make fresh user and reinstall ubuntu, but its still there.

P.S. if I do

```
rvm install macruby-0.12
```

I got error like this, of cource

```
MacRuby can only be installed on a Darwin OS.
MacRuby can only be installed on a Darwin OS.
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/12.04/x86_64/macruby-0.12.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
RVM does not have prediction for required space for macruby-0.12, assuming 150MB should be enough, let us know if it was not.
MacRuby can only be installed on a Darwin OS.
```

P.S.S
I tried /bin/bash --login etc
Couple of moths before with older RVM (when each time i got message about .rvmrc deprecated) it was all OK, but once I had to upgrade...

Comment: Ok, thanks for fast responses and sorry for my poor english and being unable to speak clear.

Step by step:
1) Install fresh ubuntu 12.04
2) run: \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
3) run: rvm use
4) see the error message about macruby. I aint goona install macruby. I want to use any ruby version (for example, 2.1.1, the latest). I dont know where the message about Darwin OS from and why do I see macruby error. I posted the last peace of code because I tried to run thing that was purposed in terminal (I know that I cant  install macruby on Ubuntu)

Comment: Or what do I do wrong?
For example, I wannt running "rvm use" to show me currently used version of ruby and gemset name.

Comment: I get the same error on Debian.

Answer (score 0):

for checking what ruby is being used run:

```
rvm current
```

as for `rvm use`, it's a but, you should get a help screen, the usage is:

```
rvm use ruby-version@gemset
```

where most of the components are optional, but at least one has to be given

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with multi-user rvm. This is what helped me:

`rvm implode` # uninstall the whole rvm

Then I installed rvm 1.25.27 and the problem was gone. Just upgrading rvm did not help.

```
user@host:~$ rvm use
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2
```